# How to test what your PDF looks like without installed (special) fonts

Tags: fonts, pdf, embed

I remember that Adobe Acrobat used to allow to switch between a view of your document based on installed **and** embedded fonts and a view based on **embedded fonts only**.

That option no longer seems to be available in Adobe Acrobat.

How can I view a PDF on my PC as if there were no fonts installed, or only Windows standard fonts for that matter?

Comment: Hi. Are you not perhaps over thinking this?  As far as I know, Adobe Reader will always display embedded fonts, assuming of course that the fonts are in fact embeddable, and have actually been embedded in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'm trying to see the document as it will be seen by my audience, who might not have all document fonts installed. Unfortunately, while Adobe Acrobat does show embedded fonts, it does so with very cryptic names from which I can't tell if indeed all fonts are embedded.

Comment: Generally speaking, if the PDF does not have all the fonts embedded, then you can never know how it will look on other people's devices (unless the non-embedded fonts are the one of the 14 built-in PDF fonts). On the other hand, if all the fonts are embedded, then you know how it will look on any other device. It sounds like you have some doubts whether the fonts are actually embedded or not? Why do you think you are getting misleading info in that regard (which is possible)?

Comment: Can't you just open it on your phone? Your phone should have a fairly limited font library of standard fonts.